# Canvas game Error

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a simple game loop and trying to use OOP paradigm in JS. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<body onload="Game.OnLoad('gameField')" onkeydown="Game.KeyDown(event)">
    <p id="info">1</p>
    <p id="info2">2</p>
    <canvas id="gameField" 
            width="896px" 
            height="717px" 
            class="game-field" 
            style="border: 4px solid aqua"
            onclick="Game.MouseClick(event)"></canvas>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// class Timer
// version: 1
// only tick() functionality available
// right now
function Timer() {
    var date = new Date();

    var prevTick = 0;
    var currTick = 0;
    // update timer with tick
    this.tick = function() {
        prevTick = currTick;
        currTick = date.getTime();
    }
    // get time between two ticks
    this.getLastTickInterval = function() {
        return currTick - prevTick;
    }
}

// global object Game
// which handles game loop
// and provide interfaces for     
var Game = new function() {
    // variables:
    this.canvas = 0;
    var gameLoopId = 0;
    this.timer = new Timer();
    // events:
    this.KeyDown = function(e) {}

    // game loop:    
    this.Run = function() {
        this.timer.tick();
        this.Update(this.timer.getLastTickInterval());
        this.Draw();
    }
    this.Update = function(dt) {
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = dt;
    }
    this.Draw = function() {}
    this.StopGameLoop = function() {
        clearInterval(gameLoopId);
    }
    this.OnLoad = function(canvasName) {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);
        this.timer.tick();

        // start game loop
        setInterval(this.Run, 1000);
    }
}​
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8263/4/))

I'm trying to make Game class global. Other classes must be instantinated using `new`.

Classes Game and Timer are placed in different files called Game.js and Timer.js. When I run this code in Chrome I got an error in DevTools: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'tick' of undefined"` in `Game.Run` function at the line `this.timer.tick();`

So I wonder, what is the problem with my code? Thanks for reply.

Comment: One note: you probably shouldn't be exposing all of those methods unless you have use cases where you'll need to access them outside of the scope of `Game`. Also, standard convention is to use a leading Upper case for Classes only, and not methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the context. When you're calling tick `this` is window, not Game.
You can handle this, for example, by setting:

```
var self = this;        
this.Run = function() {
    self.timer.tick();
    self.Update(self.timer.getLastTickInterval());
    self.Draw();
}
```

Comment: True, the fiddle supplied by the OP was invalid, [here is updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8263/7/) with your fix.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider in your code :

Concerning your issue, methode like setInterval or setTimeout loose the context. Easiest solution is to bind a context to the callback :

```
setInterval(this.Run.bind(this), 1000);
```

Secondly, avoid adding private methode inside an object function. In that case, every instance of Game will have its own set of functions (memory leak).
Prefer using prototypes :

```
function Game () {
    this.canvas = null;
}
Game.prototype = {
    init: function() {}
    render: function () {}
};
```

Lastly, I see you redraw every seconds, which is ok. But if you want 60fps, you can use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for drawing oriented loops.

ps: just to be very nitpicking, functions' name should be camelCase so starting with lower case.